# How to Delete Table from Database permanently in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've generated a scaffold and then migrated my database. After that, I destroyed my scaffolding and then generated scaffold again and try to migrate my database but I got an error that this table already exists. How can I delete that table from the database?

Comment: If you want to delete a table from database in rails, you can do it using migration. However, if you're using database such as MySQL, or PostgreSQL, you can log in and connect to your database and drop individual tables.

Comment: Have you already looked at `rake db:rollback`?

Comment: before destroying scaffold have you run `rake db:rollback` command?

Comment: Yes, I did both things correctly.

Comment: When I'm used "ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:your_table_name)" to delete table on console, it says no such table exists, but when I migrate database after generation scaffold It says table already exists.

Comment: Just install the DB client install maybe PgAdmin if you are using postgres or Mysql client set it up and delete the table manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't pushed your code then the solution given by @Cryptex Technologies works fine. But if you have(i.e if you are using version control) then i won't recommend that approach. In that case you should create a new migration something like this:

```
class RemoveTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    drop_table :table_name
  end

  def down
    create_table :table_name do |t|
      t.string :field_name_1
      t.text :field_name_2
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :table_name, :field_name_1, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted if it works. That way it will help those who get struck at the same point.

Answer (score 2):

One other easy way to do so :

open rails console and use this command :
`ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:your_table_name)`

Comment: When I'm used "ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:your_table_name)" to delete table on console, it says no such table exists, but when I migrate database after generation scaffold It says table already exists.

Comment: This is the correct answer, no need for the migration

Answer (score 1):

Rails automatically generates migration, thanks to the command line generator.
For instance, if you want to remove the Users Table write a command line statement like this:

`rails generate migration DropUsersTable`

This will generate the empty .rb file in /db/migrate/ that still needs to be filled to drop the “Users” table in this case.

A Quick-and-Dirty™ implementation would look like this:

```
class DropUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :users
  end
  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

It’s “correct” as it shows that the migration is one-way only and should not/can not be reversed. But in order to make a truly clean job in case these modifications were to be reversed we need to have a symmetrical migration (assuming we could recover the lost data), which we can do by declaring all the fields of our table in the migration file:

```
class Dropusers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This can be long if the model is complex, but it ensures full reversibility.
Here again, changes will enter effect as usual after running `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

To delete that table, you need to run the command

```
rake db:rollback
```

and if you want to delete the database of your current application.
then you need to run the command

```
rake db:drop.
```